# Pandoc Error: ! missing $ inserted

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I was trying to convert a markdown file to pdf using Pandoc. The markdown is written in Atom editor. For simplicity I am just including the equation only.

The markdown file content is

```
\[
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}= \mathrm{K}(\theta)\left( \frac{\partial h}{\partial z}\right) +1
\]
```

I run the following command from PowerShell

```
pandoc testfile1.md -s -o testfile1.pdf
```

and the following error was produced:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.53 {[} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
```

The preview is able to display formula but produces an error while conversion. If I replace `\[` and `\]` by `$$` i receive required output.

My question is: Can I not use `\[` and `\]`?

I am also attaching snapshorts

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: Can I not use `\[` and `\]`?

No, you can't. In [pandoc markdown](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math):

> Anything between two $ characters will be treated as TeX math.

Comment: This is the case because `\[` and `\]` already have meaning in Markdown. There is no way for the Markdown parser to distinguish between the escaped bracket (from Markdown's syntax) and the math deliminator. Therefore, in Markdown, you have to use the alternate `$$` syntax.

Comment: Using `\[` and `\]` should work in a LaTeX environment: `\begin{env} \[ \] \end{env}`, because pandoc doesn't parse markdown in latex-environments.

Comment: @mgansler yes, but there's really no good reason to use `\begin{env} \[ X \] \end{env}` instead of just `$$ X $$`

Comment: I just wanted to mention it because sometimes Markdown isn't enough. And if you need some LaTeX-native environment anyway you can use `\[ \]`, I didn't want to imply that you should use a LaTeX env just for math :)